# Появляется пустое место под страницей

Tags: html, css

Делаю приложение на ElectronJS.
Сверху панель вкладок. Под панелью контент вкладок. На первой вкладке есть футтер.
Долго разбирался как это сделать и у меня получилось, но появилась полоса прокрутки, а под футтером появилось много пустого места. Заранее огромное спасибо, тому, кто объяснит, из-за чего подобное случается

p.s. прокрутки страницы быть вообще не должно

UPD. Я понял в чём проблема, проблема в том, что я неправильно скрыл объекты через visibility: hidden, а надо было через display: none. То есть у меня скрытые объекты занимали место, а в остальном я всё правильно сделал

```css
*{padding: 0;margin: 0;border: 0;}
html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background-color: red;
  height: 100%;
}

.tabs {
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.tabs__nav {
  background-color: gray;
  height: 64px;
}
.tabs__content {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
.tabs__pane {
  height: 100%;
  visibility: hidden;
}
.tabs__pane_show {
  visibility: visible;
}

.main-tab {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.main-tab__content {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}
.main-tab__footer {
  background-color: gray;
  height: 64px;
}

/*# sourceMappingURL=style.css.map */
```

```html
<body>
<div class="tabs">
    <div class="tabs__nav">
        <a class="tabs__link tabs__link_active" href="#content-1">Вкладка 1</a>
        <a class="tabs__link" href="#content-2">Вкладка 2</a>
        <a class="tabs__link" href="#content-3">Вкладка 3</a>
    </div>
    <div class="tabs__content">
        <div class="tabs__pane tabs__pane_show" id="content-1">
            <div class="main-tab">
                <div class="main-tab__content"></div>
                <div class="main-tab__footer"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="tabs__pane" id="content-2">
            Содержимое 2...
        </div>
        <div class="tabs__pane" id="content-3">
            Содержимое 3...
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Долго пытался понять что и как, но так толком ничего и не понял, но если убрать  
 `height: 100%;` у `.tabs__pane`, то вроде все нормально.
Я бы посоветовал попробовать гриды, мне кажется ими легче.

Comment: Спасибо, твой ответ натолкнул меня на решение. Я понял в чём проблема, проблема в том, что я неправильно скрыл объекты через visibility: hidden, а надо было через display: none. То есть у меня скрытые объекты занимали место, а в остальном я всё правильно сделал

Comment: И все же посмотри в сторону гридов) Все же проще ими верстать)